# How can I test this function with Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to unit test a typewriter function but the value received is undefined no matter what I do.

I've looked at the Jest docs and I've also tried async with no luck.

```
let speed = 120;

  function typeWriter(id, text) {
    return function () {
      if (text) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += text[0];
        setTimeout(typeWriter(id, text.slice(1)), speed);
      }
    };
  }
typeWriter("job-title", "Web Developer")();
```

I'm expecting the innerHTML value of the element with an id of job-title to be Web Developer instead of undefined.

Comment: What do you mean by output?

Comment: The typewriter function takes an element's id and a string value which will be added to the targeted element one character at a time. So the output will be the value of the targeted element's innerHTML value.

Comment: When I run this script I do see `Web Developer` in the element. What are you seeing? undefined? (Oh, as an aside, pls use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` as your code has a security vulnerability with `innerHTML`.)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Maybe I should've been clearer, it works fine in the browser but I'm unable to successfully test it with Jest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `Jest` [Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks) like this:

```
let speed = 120;

function typeWriter(id, text) {
  return function () {
    if (text) {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += text[0];
      setTimeout(typeWriter(id, text.slice(1)), speed);
    }
  };
}

describe('typeWriter', () => {
  beforeEach(() => { jest.useFakeTimers(); });
  afterEach(() => { jest.useRealTimers(); });

  it('should work', () => {
    document.body.innerHTML = '<div><span id="job-title"></span></div>';
    const text = "Web Developer";

    typeWriter("job-title", text)();

    for (let i = 1; i <= text.length; i++) {
      expect(document.getElementById('job-title').innerHTML).toBe(text.substring(0, i));
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(speed);
    }
  });
});
```